# How can I change the width of all panels, when user changes width of one panel?

Tags: extjs

I use Ext JS. And I have a list of "panels". When user changes  width of one panel, I need to change  width of another panels automatically. Now when user changes one panel, another panels are not changed. Here is my code:

```
for (i = 0; i < resources.length; i++) {
                table.add({
                    xtype: 'panel',
                    title: resources[i].name,
                    id: prefixResourceId + resources[i].id,

                    height: constHeight,
                    resizable:{
                        pinned:false,
                        dynamic:true,
                        floating:true
                    },
                    width: widthConst,
                    layout: 'fit'
                });

            }
```

I tryed to use this code:

```
listeners: {
                     resize: function(p) {
                          new Ext.Resizable(p.getEl(), {
                              pinned:false,
                              dynamic:true,
                              resizeElement: function() {
                                  //this block works only when page are loaded
                              }
                          });
                      }
```

insdead of this:

```
resizable:{
                        pinned:false,
                        dynamic:true,
                        floating:true
                    },
```

But result is the same.
How can I change the width of all panels, when user changes width of one panel?

Answer (score 0):

Put all the panels inside a surrounding panel, let the user change the size of this one, and all the contained panels will adapt their size automatically.